# Right click indicator for mouse pointer

Tags: mouse-pointer

I want to have a visual effect for the mouse pointer so that some animation appears to indicate a mouse right click. That would be useful for screencasts. I know there is an app called key-mon that can draw a red circle around the pointer whenever I click, but how do I enable it only for right-clicking? Is there a way I can do that other than with key-mon in Ubuntu?